# How to add new posts like page in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am setting up a GitHub page which uses Jekyll. I know how to create a new post, new page. I wanted a new "posts" like the page, wherein I can add posts which I want to. So there will be a posts page (by default) and there will be some other page say blog, both of which shows some posts in the appropriate category.

Comment: I‘m not sure whether I understand what your actual question is. Are you asking how to create category pages, i.e. a separate page which lists *all* posts, or just all posts with a specific category?

Comment: My home page contains links to posts, for which I just write the .md file and put it in _posts folder. I want to do a similar thing for some non-home page, where say I put the .md file in _xyz folder, and those posts are displayed in xyz page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a page which [lists all posts which have a certain category or tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#displaying-post-categories-or-tags).
   Example code from the link:

   ```
   ---
   layout: page
   ---

   {% for post in site.categories[page.category] %}
       <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">
         {{ post.title }}
       </a>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. If the .md files you are talking about aren't posts, you can use [Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).
   Here's example code from the link tailored to your `xyz` example - basically, you define your collection in the config file:

   ```
   collections:
   - xyz
   ```

   Then, you create .md files in an `_xyz` folder, and you can display a list of them like this:

   ```
   {% for item in site.xyz %}
     <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
     <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
     <p><a href = "{{ item.url }}" >{{ item.title }}</a></p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: Thanks Christian !! :)